# Linker script to add tables to rodata segment

Tags: gcc, linker, clang, elf

I'm trying to port some code that builds up tables at compile time.  I don't want to maintain a stand alone linking script for this.  I just want to add a few things to all the magic that the compiler is already doing for linking.

At compile time, entries for the table are marked with a specially named section.  Then some linker commands (see below) assemble everything with that name into a table with symbols for the start and end.  This is similar to how C++ does static initializers, but in user level code.

I'm using clang at the moment, but I understand it to be the same as gcc for this.

This mini linking script is almost the right thing, but how do I tell the linker that this section should be included in rodata?

```
SECTIONS {
    _bt_channels_area : SUBALIGN(4)
    {
            _bt_l2cap_fixed_chan_list_start = .;
            KEEP(*(SORT("._bt_l2cap_fixed_chan.static.*")))
            _bt_l2cap_fixed_chan_list_end = .;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which compiler, or specifically, which linker are you using? (Please edit your post with the answer as text.)  There is no standard language for the input or configuration to a linker.  There are a lot of compilers and linkers out there.

Comment: BTW, the ELF file format is language independent, so you can remove the language tags.  Many linkers are language independent (front end compilers would generate symbols whether compiling FORTRAN or C).